# chrome.management.get not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

```
function Notify(header,content,image){
    var note = webkitNotifications.createNotification(image||"",header,content);
    note.show();
return note;}


var extensions = ["pbjhaapnigfhipfahcfkeakpcgkmnklc"];

function CheckReload(){
    for(var CN=0;CN<extensions.length;CN++){
        var id = extensions[CN];
        var ex = chrome.management.get(id);
        console.log("Checking",ex,"-",id);
        if(!ex.enabled){
            Notify("Extension reloaded!",ex.name+" was found crashed, and reloaded!");
            chrome.management.setEnabled(id,true);
        }
     }
}
setInterval(CheckReload,1000);
```

Ok, so what I was expecting was for this to check the extensions in the "extensions" array, and if they weren't enabled it would create a notification saying that it wasn't, and then enable it.
However, chrome.management.get(id) seems to be returning undefined.

I expected an output like:
Checking Object - [id]

Instead, what I got was:
Checking undefined - pbjhaapnigfhipfahcfkeakpcgkmnklc
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined

How can I fix this?

Comment: Note that `webkitNotifications.createNotification` is deprecated, and will soon be removed. It already stopped working on Windows and ChromeOS (reference: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktop_notifications.html)

Comment: @ChrisP is there something I'm not getting? It looks like what's being removed is creating notifications with HTML, not creating notifications with the createNotification method?

Comment: My bad, I misread your code. You're correct, only the createHTMLNotification will be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the methods provided by chrome don't return a value, instead they take a callback function as a parameter, and call that function with the wanted result.
You should replace your code by

```
chrome.management.get(id, function(ex) {
    console.log("Checking",ex,"-",id);
    if(!ex.enabled){
        Notify("Extension reloaded!",ex.name+" was found crashed, and reloaded!");
        chrome.management.setEnabled(id,true);
    }
});
```

See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html#method-get for details.

Comment: I did exact what you do and get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` . Also I have inserted the management in permissions of `manifest.json`. what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your code from an extensions, make sure that your extension have permissions to management.